# Bruns-Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay Rings, Exercise 6.4.17 (b)

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, cohen-macaulay

> Let $k$ be an infinite field,
>   $S=k[x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}]/(x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21})$.
>   Let $p=(x_{11},x_{12})$, $q=(x_{21},x_{22})$. Show that
>
> (i) $p$ and $q$ are prime ideals in $S$ and maximal Cohen-Macaulay
>   $S$-modules.
>
> (ii) $p^j$ and $q^j$ are not Cohen-Macaulay for $j\geq 2$.

This question is from Bruns-Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Exercise 6.4.17 (b). I am not sure here we say an ideal $p$ is Cohen-Macaulay, means $p$ as module is Cohen-Macaulay or its quotient ring $S/p$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when an ideal $I$ is called Cohen-Macaulay, it is the quotient ring $R/I$ that is intended to be Cohen-Macaulay. However, in this case, $\dim S = 3$ but $S/p \cong k[x_{21}, x_{22}]$ $\implies \dim S/p = 2$, so $S/p$ is not maximal Cohen-Macaulay as an $S$-module (although $S/p$ is CM, either as an $S$-module or as a ring, and similarly $S/p^j$ is not CM for $j \ge 2$).

Note that any $S$-ideal $I$, viewed as an $S$-module, has trivial annihilator (since $S$ is a domain), so $\dim I := \dim S/\text{ann}_S(I) = \dim S$. Finally, the following fact (proven using the Depth Lemma) suffices to finish the problem:

**Proposition:** Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring, and $I$ an $R$-ideal with $\text{depth}(R) > \text{depth}(R/I)$. Then viewing $I$ as an $R$-module, $\text{depth}(I) = \text{depth}(R/I)+1$.

Comment: Coming back to the problem, is it obvious that for $j\ge 2$ we have $\operatorname{depth}S/\mathfrak p^j<2$?

Comment: @user26857: I agree that there is more to be said about the problem in Bruns-Herzog, but seeing as how the OP seems to have little interest left in the question, I feel slightly less inclined to put forth more effort (besides the fact that the OP seemed only to ask about the definition of CM for an ideal).

Comment: Actually just now I've noticed that the OP asked only about the definition of CMness of an ideal. (To be honest, I don't get the hint in Bruns and Herzog and I'd be curious how to use Hilbert-Burch for (ii). It seems to me that one can argue in a simpler manner: $x_{21},x_{22}$ is a sop for $S/p^j$ which is not a regular sequence.)

Comment: @user26857: After seeing your comment, I decided to think some more about this. It seems that Bruns-Herzog is applying Hilbert-Burch to the ideals $P_j := p^j + (x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21})$ in the polynomial ring. If $\text{depth}(S/p^j) = 2$ for some $j \ge 2$, then by Hilbert-Burch, $\mu(P_j) \le 3$ (since $P_j$ is not in the cube of the homogeneous maximal ideal) which is false. I also think that your argument is very clear though, and finishes the problem immediately